# Progress Bar PHP WITH AJAX For Insert Data TO MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

I would like to insert some record from one table (TblNilaiTempEx) to another table (TblNilaiEx), I have  one method to do that like this:

```
public function actionImport()
{   
        $model = TblNilaiTempEx::find()
        ->select([
        'tbl_nilai_temp.id as id_nilai_temp',
        'tbl_nilai_temp.tbl_krs_id',
        'tbl_nilai_temp.nilai_tugas',
        'tbl_nilai_temp.nilai_praktek',
        'tbl_nilai_temp.nilai_uts',
        'tbl_nilai_temp.nilai_uas',
        'tbl_nilai_temp.nilai_total',
        'tbl_nilai_temp.nilai_huruf',
        'tbl_nilai_temp.file_template_id'
        ])
        ->from('tbl_nilai_temp')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_krs','tbl_krs.id=tbl_nilai_temp.tbl_krs_id')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_jadwal','tbl_jadwal.id=tbl_krs.tbl_jadwal_id')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_matakuliah','tbl_matakuliah.id=tbl_jadwal.tbl_matakuliah_id')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_kurikulum','tbl_kurikulum.id=tbl_matakuliah.tbl_kurikulum_id')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_program_studi','tbl_program_studi.id=tbl_kurikulum.tbl_program_studi_id')
        ->andWhere('tbl_matakuliah.tbl_matakuliah_jenis_id in (2,3,4,5,6) and tbl_nilai_temp.status_sync=0')
        ->asArray()
        ->limit(5)
        ->all();
        foreach($model as $modelNilaiTemp) {
            $modelNilai=new TblNilaiEx;
            $modelNilai->tbl_krs_id =$modelNilaiTemp['tbl_krs_id'];
            $modelNilai->nilai_tugas =$modelNilaiTemp['nilai_tugas'];
            $modelNilai->nilai_praktek = $modelNilaiTemp['nilai_praktek'];
            $modelNilai->nilai_uts = $modelNilaiTemp['nilai_uts'];
            $modelNilai->nilai_uas = $modelNilaiTemp['nilai_uas'];
            $modelNilai->nilai_total = $modelNilaiTemp['nilai_total'];
            $modelNilai->nilai_huruf =  $modelNilaiTemp['nilai_huruf'];
            $modelNilai->file_template_id =$modelNilaiTemp['file_template_id'];
            $modelNilai->tbl_nilai_rumus_id =1;
            $modelNilai->status_eks =4;
            $modelNilai->created_by=1;

            $modelNilai->tbl_nilai_temp_id=$modelNilaiTemp['id_nilai_temp'];

            if($modelNilai->save()) {
              echo "success";
            } else {
               echo "Fail";
            }
            sleep(2);
            
        }
```

In the View, i want show progress bar during the import progress, so i have other method to check how many record the import progress has done, like this:

```
public function actionCheckImport()
{
    $model=TblNilaiEx::find()
    ->andWhere('tbl_nilai_temp_id IS NOT NULL')
    ->all();
    return count($model);
}
```

Then in the View, i made a script to display progress in progress bar like this:

```
    <?php
        $js = <<<JS
       
        var clear_timer;
        $('.sync-form').submit(function(event) {
    
                $('#message').html('');
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                //Example Just 5 data
                $('#total_data').text('5');
                clear_timer = setInterval(check_imported_data, 1000);
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/sync-nilai-ta/import",
                    method:"POST",
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    //dataType:"json",
                    contentType:false,
                    cache:false,
                    processData:false,
                    beforeSend:function(){
                        $('#sync-button').attr('disabled','disabled');
                        $('#sync-button').val('Synchronizing');
    
                    },
                })
                
            }
        );
        function check_imported_data()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"/sync-nilai-ta/check-import",
                beforeSend:function(data){
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
                    var total_data = $('#total_data').text();
                    var width = Math.round((data/total_data)*100);
                    $('#process_data').text(data);
                    $('.progress-bar').css('width', width + '%');
    
                    $('#message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Data Successfully Imported</div>');
                    if(data >= 5 ) {
                        clearInterval(clear_timer);
                    }
    
                }
            })
            
        }
       
    JS;
    $this->registerJs($js);
    ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'options'=>['class' => 'sync-form']
        ]); ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Sync', ['class' => 'btn btn-success','id'=>'sync-button']) ?>
        </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    <div class="form-group" id="process">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                <span id="process_data"></span> - <span id="total_data"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The data have been successfully imported, the problem is the progress bar does not gradualy increase (not  gradualy change until 100%), the progress bar just show 100% after all data imported, I would like the progress bar gradualy change until 100%, any help?Thanks for all.

Comment: Do the php scripts for importing and checking progress use sessions? If they do look into session locking. Only one process can look at a session by default so can't have 2 scripts running simultaneously.

Comment: @Flewz, thank you very much, you are right, session locking is my problem, I have solved the problem by add Opening and Closing Sessions in each method

Comment: Extra tip. You can use `TblNilaiEx::find()->andWhere('tbl_nilai_temp_id IS NOT NULL')->count();` instead of loading all models and using `count()` function.

Comment: Btw. if you are going to copy bigger amount of rows (based on the fact that you need progress bar) you might want to consider using [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) instead of loading each row in php then writing it back.